# Setting a panel in an hbox layout to the parent height?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

I had a panel with a child-panel with a `fit` layout.

Now I want to add a second childpanel on the right,
so I set the layout to `hbox` and added the second panel after the first.

But now the children don't have the **height** of the parent anymore.

The `flex` option took care of the width, **what takes care of the height**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The align, it does an autoheight by default (the height of you panel). But you can make it stretch to the parent container by adding this in the layout:

```
layout: {
   type: 'hbox',
   align: 'stretch'  //stretch vertically to parent
}
```

An explenation here: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.layout.container.HBox-cfg-align

Comment: Ah.. I tried to configure the parent and the child panels, but not the layout itself. Thank you.

Comment: yes, but I have to wait 10min before I can accept the answer :)